# Chrome autofill AngularJS field bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am attempting to work around a bug I have been noticing when using a custom Angular directive and Chrome's autofill. I have written a directive for a phone number field. This directive adds dashes "-" to the phone number field (so the user does not have to add any dashes when typing in their number).

The directive, is listed below

```
app.directive("phoneNumberValidator", function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            var domElement = elem[0]; // Get DOM element
            var phoneNumberRegex = new RegExp("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}"); // Phone number regex
            var cursorIndex; // Index where the cursor should be

            // Create a parser to alter and validate if our
            // value is a valid phone number
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {

                // If our value is non-existent, we return undefined
                // WHY?: an angular model value should be undefined if it is empty
                if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null || value == "") {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalidFormat', true); // No invalid format if the value of the phone number is empty
                    return undefined;
                }

                // PARSER LOGIC
                // =compare our value to a modified value after it has
                // been transformed into a "nice" phone number. If these
                // values are different, we set the viewValue to 
                // the "nice" phone number. If these values are the same,
                // we render the viewValue (aka. "nice" phone number)
                var prevValue, nextValue;

                prevValue = value;
                nextValue = value.replace(/[\D]/gi, ""); // Strip all non-digits

                // Make the "nice" phone number
                if (nextValue.length >= 4 && nextValue.length <= 6) {
                    nextValue = nextValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})?/, "$1-$2");
                } else if (nextValue.length >= 7 && nextValue.length <= 10) {
                    nextValue = nextValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})?/, "$1-$2-$3");
                }

                // Save the correct index where the custor should be
                // WHY?: we do this here because "ctrl.$render()" shifts
                // the cursor index to the end of the phone number
                cursorIndex = domElement.selectionStart;

                if (prevValue != nextValue) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(nextValue); // *Calling this function will run all functions in ctrl.$parsers!
                } else {
                    ctrl.$render(); // Render the new, "nice" phone number
                }

                // If our cursor lands on an index where a dash "-" is,
                // move it up by one
                if (cursorIndex == 4 || cursorIndex == 8) {
                    cursorIndex = cursorIndex + 1;
                }

                var valid = phoneNumberRegex.test(value); // Test the validity of our phone number
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalidFormat', valid); // Set the validity of the phone number field
                domElement.setSelectionRange(cursorIndex, cursorIndex); // Assign the cursor to the correct index

                return value; // Return the updated value
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The **problem** lies when Chrome autofills this field. By using the Batarang extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), I am able to see the scope values that are in use on my page. 
 When I have Chrome **autofill** my phone number field, with a value of "1234567899", my Angular phone field's value in my `$scope` is 1234567899 (it should be: "123-546-7899").

Placing a breakpoint in my directive will enable me to see that the directive is indeed being run in my browser when Chrome autofills my field, but the `$scope.PhoneNumber` field value is 1234567899, instead of 123-456-7899. **In short, the $viewModel gets updated properly when autofilling, but the $modelValue does not**

Can I programatically change the `$modelValue` to reflect the proper value that should remain in `$scope.PhoneNumber` once Chrome autofills the phone field?

**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWn7Hz720LIRp0JzpHjq?p=preview)**

Comment: Can you please add a runnable example in a plnkr.co?

Comment: Yes, I will get one up for this question

Comment: Added a plunkr, you'll have to have an autofill phone number that contains no dashes before browsing the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected, but it's definitely confusing. 
Bottom line: $setViewValue is not made to be called inside a parser, because $setViewValue itself triggers the complete $parsers, $validators pipeline up to the actual model value.
So what happens?
If the value is different, you call another $setViewValue. Because the pipeline is synchronous, it runs the $parsers again before the first run finishes! So the return value from the first time the parser runs is what is actually set to the model. I would suggest you don't call $setViewValue in the parser, but simply set the $viewValue and call $render.

You can see the problem also when you don't have autofill (or simple paste also works). Enter 1234 (separately), and you will see that the model is 1234, because that is the original value. Only when enter 5, will the value be 123-45, because at this point the view is already updated with the dash.

It's simply a weak API on the angular side. There is no clear way to transform the view, so people abuse the parsers. Technically, what I would suggest is to overwrite the $setViewValue fn, so the value that is passed to the parsers is already correctly formatted.

Updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mAfkQ2DjbCdtFW3oAhBc?p=preview

```
if (prevValue != nextValue) {
    ctrl.$viewValue = nextValue;
    ctrl.$render();
}

if (cursorIndex == 4 || cursorIndex == 8) {
    cursorIndex = cursorIndex + 1;
}

var valid = phoneNumberRegex.test(nextValue);
ctrl.$setValidity('invalidFormat', valid);
domElement.setSelectionRange(cursorIndex, cursorIndex);


return nextValue;
```

Comment: Thank you for identifying this, I couldn't understand what was going on. However, it is the call to `$render()` that takes the `$viewValue` and syncs it to the `$modelValue`? I just want to make sure I understand this

Comment: Angular core calls $render only when the model changes. Then the order is this: formatters -> assign viewValue -> validators -> render(). When the view changes because of an input event etc., the order is setViewValue - parsers - validators - model update.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this